# Virtual explicit conversion operator overriding

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, overriding, explicit

I have a class `Base` defining an `explicit operator bool`:

```
struct Base {
    virtual explicit operator bool() const {
        return true;
    }
};
```

And I have a subclass `Derived`, defining an `operator bool`:

```
struct Derived : Base {
    operator bool() const override {
        return false;
    }
};
```

As you can observe, `Derived::operator bool` is explicitly not marked `explicit`, but marked `override`, so I expected the compiler to complain. However, both gcc and clang seem to agree that this is valid. Was my expectation unreasonable?

Moreover, if I use the classes as follows, `TakesBool(base)` does not compile (as expected), but `TakesBool(derived)` does:

```
void TakesBool(bool b) {}

int main() {
    //Base base;     TakesBool(base); // compilation error (as expected)
    Derived derived; TakesBool(derived);
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to indicate that `Derived` has an (non-`explicit`) `operator bool`, which, however, is marked `override` without a `virtual` declaration. How is this possible?

Comment: Regarding not needing `virtual` in the derived class, if a base-class has been marked `virtual` it's implicitly implied for all derived classes as well. The `override` keyword is more of a hint for the compiler, so you don't attempt to override a function using a different signature (like declaring a function in a derived class that takes different arguments than the function in the base class). So those keywords are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Virtual dispatch still takes place.  `Base* pbase = &derived; TakesBool((bool)*pbase);` will call `Derived::operator bool`.  I guess `explicit` isn't considered part of the function's signature, so you're allowed to override an `explicit` conversion with a non-`explicit` one.  I'm not sure if this behavior is correct though.

Comment: This is like having a `protected: virtual` function in the base class with a `public: override` in the derived class.  Not a problem whatsoever.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might think that the non-`explicit` `operator bool` in `Derived` doesn't override `explicit` `operator bool` in `Base`, no, it **does**. The [explicit specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) doesn't matter, it's not a part of function signature.

From the standard, [§10.3/2 Virtual functions
[class.virtual]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#2):

(emphasis mine)

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with **the same name, parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same)** as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides `Base::vf`.

So the compiler will complain only when the name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification or ref-qualifier of the function doesn't match, the explicit specifier won't be considered.

---

<sup>You said "marked `override` without a `virtual` declaration", note that the `virtual` declaration for member function in derived class is superfluous, it's also `virtual`.</sup>

Comment: I investigated that it is possible to have a base class that has both an `explicit operator bool` and an `operator bool`, and those two are treated differently. Do you know what happens if the derived class defines `operator bool() override`? Does it override both `operator bool`s?

Comment: @phimuemue Why not just try it?

Comment: @underscore_d Yes, but I am primarily interested in an answer based on the standard.

Comment: @phimuemue I don't think [it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c21d1b23eb343109)'s possible. You can't have both `explicit operator bool` and `operator bool`. Overloading?

Comment: @phimuemue It's right there: `explicit` is not part of the signature. You cannot declare 2 functions w/ same signature regardless of place in the hierarchy. Trying it would've shown you this! songyuanyao showed the same thing for Clang, and here's GCC: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f329d16b4b8ac66b `main.cpp:9:22: error: 'virtual Base::operator bool() const' cannot be overloaded

     explicit virtual operator bool() const

                      ^~~~~~~~

main.cpp:4:13: error: with 'virtual Base::operator bool() const'

     virtual operator bool() const

             ^~~~~~~~`

Comment: @songyuanyao You are right, I can't have both. (Sorry, I misread my code. One was const, the other not.)

Comment: @phimuemue Yes, const or non-const is a part of the signature for member function. So you can override the const one or non-const one in derived class. Anyway, explicit or not doen't matter.